# python counter with target value

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to take,as  arguments, two  values: a   list    and a   target  value. It returns   the #   number  of  times   that    the target  value   appears in  the list.

```
def countTarget(myList, target):
    #initialize the counter to  zero
    counter =   0
    for element in  myList:
        #compare    the value   in  the list to the target  value
        #if they    are the same,   increment   the counter
        if  element ==  target:
            counter =   counter +   1
    return  counter
```

Comment: Ok, looks good. Are you having some kind of trouble?

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @CaseyJones then please describe the problem in the question and add relevant code, specifically, the code calling the function

Comment: Why not just do: `myList.count(target)`?

Answer (score 2):

Okay there are going to be better answers, but here's one.

```
def countTarget(myList, target):
    return sum([x == target for x in myList])
```

**Edit**

There's a much better alternative in the comments.

```
myList.count(target)
```

...

Comment: Booleans evaluate to 0 or 1 when summed. The answer is right.

Comment: This actually works. This'll count the number of appearances.

Comment: This function does work, but then again so does the OP's function, so I'm not sure this answers the question. (although it's not totally clear what the question _is_, yet)

Comment: while technically correct, this doesn't answer the question (partly OP's fault since no question was actually asked) just another way of accomplishing something that already works

Comment: You don't need to build the list first, you can `sum(x == target for x in myList)` but `list.count` seems a better fit for a single value

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class. It's a special type of *dict* that works very well for counting the frequency of a particular value inside a list (as opposed to using a dict yourself) because it will circumvent some nits like running into a `KeyError` when trying to count a target that doesn't exist in the list (`Counter` on the other hand will just return 0).

```
from collections import Counter

def countTarget(myList, target):
  return Counter(myList)[target]
```

Alternatively, you can use the bult in `count` function for lists, as mentioned in a comment below your question.

`def countTarget(myList, target): return myList.count(target)`

However, at that point your `countTarget` function isn't doing you much good. If you really want to have both objects be parameters, you can also use the count function from a static context...

`list.count(myList, target)`

But seriously, just use `myList.count(target)`. It's probably the most simple and straightforward for your use case (by the looks of it). If you need to count targets multiple times, then consider keeping your own `Counter` as mentioned before.